# Flexmix R: Latent class ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to perform a model-based clustering using a mixture of ordinal logistic regressions (for outcome, not as concomitant model) 
Does some one know if it implemented in R? For example, can I manage to use ordinal regression instead of multinomial in flexmix package?

Thanks a lot!